# How to remove gesture after implementing UIGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am using PinchGestureRecognizer and RotationGestureRecognizer both working fine. The code is as follows:

```
- (IBAction)pinchDetected:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);
    recognizer.scale = 1;
}


-(IBAction)rotationDetected:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    recognizer.rotation = 0;
}
```

with this code I am able to pinch as well as rotate my view. but on "RESET" button click I want to set my view's frame as it was before pinching or rotating.

for that I am using

```
[viewTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(80.0f, 65.0f, 160.0f, 101.0f)];
```

but my frame does not set.

so How can I set my view's frame again as it was before pinching and zooming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not changing the frame with your gesture recognisers.

You need to assign the transform back to the identity.

```
recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```

Comment: thanks for reply but when I wrote above code my pinching and rotation functionality does not work

Comment: Your code is correct for the gesture recogniser. This is to put in the "reset" method.  You will probably want `viewTwo.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity`

Answer (score 0):

Frame and transform are applied to a view in two completely separate ways (where frame is the smallest rectangle that fits a view, and transform is a representation of the underlying 2-D matrix of the view).  If you wish to return to the size the view was previously, assign `recognizer.view.transform` to `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.